# AWS ElasticSearch - status red

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

We're having an issue with ElasticSearch on AWS.

The node is in Red Status for couple of hours now. I have no idea how to recover this.

I have tried a few suggestions:

```
curl -XGET -u 'username:password' 'host:443/_cluster/allocation/explain'
```

But all of the requests are coming back with:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "master_not_discovered_exception",
        "reason" : null
      }
    ],
    "type" : "master_not_discovered_exception",
    "reason" : null
  },
  "status" : 503
}
```

The health dashboard is showing this:

[image]

Any ideas on how I can recover the instance?

UPDATE:

It looks like one of the nodes has disappeared:

24 hours ago
[image]

Now:
[image]

UPDATE:

Maybe there was too much RAM use? How do I fix it? The node is not even listed in the list of nodes. Can I curl a specific node?

[image]

UPDATE:

Ended up just re-creating the instance from beginning. Apparently Master nodes is a no-go. You are supposed to have 3 at least as when you have 2 master nodes and one of them crashes, the other one does nothing to restore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are getting the no masters discovered error then there's something pretty wrong with your deployment

you'd need to contact aws support for this, as that is what is managing the node deployment at the end of the day

Comment: Yeah looks like I have no other option but to get the support package. They refuse to do anything in sales / billing and really heard from me today about not being able to reboot instance if it's down. For now I have created a completely new cluster so I could get Magento 2 site back online with search. Thankfully it's not super complex. But my oh my I was not happy dealing with this issue.

Comment: sorry to hear that. I work at Elastic, the makers of Elasticsearch, we have hosted Elasticsearch with heaps of included features not in aws here - http://elastic.co/cloud. you can also get it via the aws marketplace

Comment: Ended up just re-creating the instance. Of course not without usual AWS BS where the Master Node check mark is hidden during the setup, but not when editing the instance. So now I'm stuck having to disable the Master Nodes and having more down time.